# Heroku local persistent storage

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, local-storage

I have created a node app with local persistent storage in a .json file. It works fine running locally, but when I deploy it to heroku the persistent storage is modified, but then erased.

Comment: What kind of local persistence?  If you mean on the server then yes.  That's how Heroku works, you need to install an addin

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Heroku does not provide any sort of persistent storage on dynos. If you need to persist files across sessions, you must use object storage such as Amazon S3.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem

Answer (score 0):

You can also setup [Active Storage using Amazon S3](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3-upload-node) as @[Max Woolf's explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42789803/1205637) stated, but you can also store in a persistent instance of a relational database like [postgres](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql) or [Amazon RDS](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/amazon-rds), which would be available on heroku as a plugin instead of using a json file.