# provide auth images by Nodejs on Heroku

Tags: node.js, express, heroku

I have a server for my mobile application coded in Nodejs.
The user can upload some photos, that only him can visit.
For that, I provide photos through express static routes, checking the token.

1. The user upload the photo through a form, at a server express route

   `$http.post('myserver.it/user/:iduser/photo', {'photo':blob})`
2. The Nodejs server loads the image and saves it in its filesystem, under

   `./photos/user/:iduser/photos`
3. Then the user's images are available as

   `http://myserver.it/user/:iduser/photo/:idphoto?token=######`

The server checks the token and, if the user is authorized, gets the photo.

It works great, but I'd like to know if it's a good solution.

Right now I deployed it on heroku, using the free plan. Is it a good and secure way to implement this feature?
Thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42775418/heroku-local-persistent-storage  c accepted answer. NO Heroku has NO persistence and S3 or similar api necessary ( input - POST pics, output - CDN/URL for pic ). Then , another Doc/Stor like Mongo for the User/Photo/Collection , a set of Urls of both photos ( large & thumb ) for a users albums.

Comment: Do you think that mongo it’s right to store images?I already use it to store the other data

Comment: that is an option . i think u need to find an implementation of a fileAdapter to do that.

Comment: That could be great, so I can keep my express route and the auth middleware to serve images.

Answer (score 0):

Depends a bit on your definition of "good" and "secure", but generally no.  You're exposing the token in the URL, so anyone with the URL will be able to get the photos for that user. Second, you're doing it over HTTP, so anyone on the same network can steal the token even if you move it to the headers or a cookie.

My first thought is for a mobile app, don't bother putting stuff on the server that's for a single user.  Just store locally.

If you have to put it on the server, save it to someplace more bulk, like S3 or similar services.  Heroku file system goes away frequently, so you can't save stuff there and expect it to remain.

Comment: actually I use https, I forgot the 's'. So let's say I can move it to the header. And I need photos available in different devices of the same account. So instead each time download/upload photos and sync the devices, I thought to serve them directly from the server.

Comment: Ok, that's better. My point about the file storage stands, though.